# Persistent typeerror on trying to getObject in S3 bucket requiring authenticated access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

Using the AWS JavaScript SDK, I am trying to read a specific S3 bucket as an authenticated Cognito user signed into a protected area of my website. I have verified that I am getting in as an authenticated user, by virtue of the valid authToken that I get after confirming my Cognito Identity. In fact, I have tested and proven out the entire Cognito flow of registering, multi-factor verifying, signing in and signing out.

For some reason, when I issue my first s3.getObject request I get the following TypeError even though I'm CERTAIN I am passing a string (the Key) as the first argument. Here's the error:

```
TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object.
```

Now, first things first, I include the JavaScript SDK via a script tag on the HTML page as follows:

```
script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.154.0.min.js"></script>
```

I have the following IAM role created by Cognito:

```
Cognito_MyAppNameAuth_Role
```

To which I have added the following S3 policy:

```
{
  "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name"
},
{
  "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": "s3:GetObject",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"
}
```

Note: the Visual Editor inserted those Sids automatically after I edited it.

Now, the code that I execute to read my S3 bucket resides in a .js file that I include via a  tag. It runs after the  loads...

```
<body onLoad="bodyOnLoad();">
```

The first thing the code does is verify the user credentials. I get the User Pool; then I get the current user. Then I get the session. And then I call for the user credentials using AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials() as follows:

```
AWS.config.update({ //testing... 12/29
  region: 'us-east-1',
  accessKeyId: 'anything',
  secretAccessKey: 'anything',
  credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
     IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:numbers-and-letters-and-bears-oh-my',
     Logins: {
        'cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1-xxxyyyxxx': session.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
        }
     })
});
```

I literally specify "anything" for the accessKeyId and secretAccessKey, as I do not believe those are required. When this runs, there are No errors. Everything appears in order with verifying my authenticated user belonging to the required Cognito Identity Pool.

Here is the s3.getObject attempt that happens next and results in the TypeError given above:

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
  params: {
    Bucket: 'my-bucket-name'
  }
});

var params = {
  Bucket: 'my-bucket-name',
  Key: 'index.json'
};

s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    // EXECUTION LANDS HERE!
    callback(err);
    return;
  }

  const content = data.Body.toString('utf-8');
  callback(null, content);
});
}
```

I have tried many permutations on the way I'm passing params to the getObject method. Including..

```
s3.getObject({Key: 'index.json'}, (err, data) => { ... }
```

I get the same error every time.
What in the world am I doing wrong???
Thank you in advance!!!

**UPDATE 1/1/2019 - HNY!**

Responding to John below, I modified my code to move everything into the same scope. (Thanks again.) Good advice, but I'm still getting the same TypeError (shown above). Now, I think John may be right that the real problem is with my authentication or the Identity Pool policy. If I remove the bogus accessKeyId and secretAccessKey from the AWS.config.update (as John removed these in his example) I do get a different error: I get a 400 error and then this..

```
Error: Invalid login token. Issuer doesn't match providerName
```

Here's the code that I have in config.js:

```
window._config = {
    cognito: {
        userPoolId: 'user-pool-id',
        userPoolClientId: 'user-pool-client-id',
        region: 'us-east-1'
    },
    api: {
        invokeUrl: 'https://<invoke-url>.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod'
    }
};
```

Here's the new code flow after rolling all into the same scope:

```
function loadFileFromS3(key, callback) {
  console.log('loadFileFromS3: ' + key); //key is 'index.json'

  var poolData = {
      UserPoolId: _config.cognito.userPoolId,
      ClientId: _config.cognito.userPoolClientId
  };

  var userPool;

  userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);

  if (typeof AWSCognito !== 'undefined') {
      AWSCognito.config.region = _config.cognito.region;
  }

  var cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();

  if (cognitoUser) {
      cognitoUser.getSession(function sessionCallback(err, session) {
          if (err) {
              reject(err);
          } else if (!session.isValid()) {
              resolve(null);
          } else {
              console.log('authToken is ' + session.getIdToken().getJwtToken());
              // Configure the credentials provider to use your identity pool
              AWS.config.update({ //testing... 12/29
                region: 'us-east-1',
                accessKeyId: 'anything', //remove gives me 400 error as shown above
                secretAccessKey: 'anything', // 
                credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
                  IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:<identity-pool-id>',
                  Logins: {
                    'cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1-<user-pool-id>': session.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
                  }
                })
              });
              console.log('AWS.config update happened...');

              // call refresh to authenticate user and get credentials
              AWS.config.credentials.refresh((error) => {
                if (error) {
                  console.error(error);
                } else {
                  console.log('Success');
                  // NOTE: The credential are valid HERE
                  const s3 = new AWS.S3({
                    apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
                    params: {
                      Bucket: 'my-bucket-name'
                    }
                  });
                  var params = {
                    Bucket: 'my-bucket-name',
                    Key: key
                  };

                  console.log('s3.getObject with key: ' + key);
                  s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
                    if (err) {
                      console.log('getObject ERROR: ' + err);
                      callback(err);
                      return;
                    }

                    const content = data.Body.toString('utf-8');
                    callback(null, content);
                  });
                }
              });
          }
      });
  } else {
      resolve(null);
  }

}
```

**UPDATE**

Okay. The problem had nothing to do with the argument I was passing to `s3.getObject` and everything to do with a typo in my UserPoolId in `Logins`. I was missing an underscore. Gah! Thanks John for leading me to the fix. I would have floundered forever if you hadn't suggested I double-check.

Correcting the above code:

```
Logins: {
   'cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_<user-pool-id>': session.getIdToken().getJwtToken() //underscore after us-east-1_ !!!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your real problem is that you do not have credentials for the user.

```
AWS.config.update({ //testing... 12/29
  region: 'us-east-1',
  credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:numbers-and-letters-and-bears-oh-my',
    Logins: {
      'cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1-xxxyyyxxx': session.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
    }
  })
});

// call refresh to authenticate user and get credentials
AWS.config.credentials.refresh((error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Success');
    // NOTE: The credential are valid HERE
    // Put your S3 code HERE.
    const s3 = new AWS.S3({
      apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
      params: {
        Bucket: 'my-bucket-name'
      }
    });
    // Continue with the rest of your S3 code HERE
  }
});
// The credentials are not valid HERE
```

Comment: Thanks John. I made the changes you recommended and still get the same error. However, I think you may be right that this TypeError is masking the real problem and that it has to do with authentication or policy. Nonetheless, your advice was good and I moved everything into the same scope. I'm going to post the new code below and see if there are any other ideas from there.

Comment: It was some post somewhere that led me to include the bogus accessKeyId and secretAccessKey in the config update. I see you removed them. So I did too and that led to a 400 error: "Error: Invalid login token. Issuer doesn't match providerName". I'm not exactly sure what this means or how to deal with it. I'm investigating...

Comment: Your latest error now makes sense. Add to your question the code where you process the Cognito User. This needs to be setup correctly also.

Comment: Alrighty. As I've built my "solution" from two different AWS examples, I've been concerned all along that they might interfere with one another as I integrate and customize. Right now, the only salient code I'm thinking I've left out is the code that resides in my config.js. This goes as follows... (but I'm about to look over the Cognito code that I have across 3 different .js files, all included on the html page). 'window._config = { cognito: { userPoolId: 'user-pool-id', userPoolClientId: 'user-pool-client-id', region: 'us-east-1' }, api: { invokeUrl: //this is not invoked for now } };

Comment: Double check your `Logins` map and `IdentityPoolId` and verify that you are the correct IDs.

Comment: Ugh. I had a hyphen instead of an underscore in my UserPoolId. That solved the problem and code executes until the next error, which seems to be something entirely different. I'll update my question and mark the answer asap. Thanks brother! Happy New Year! (Corrected: I meant UserPoolId)

Comment: Excellent - glad to help. I have done a lot of work with Cognito. If you have another issue post a new question and ping me. I will try to help.